# How can the relationship $\frac{\triangle G_t}{Y_t}=\triangle \left(\frac{G_t}{Y_t}\right)$ be established?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics

The calculation below is from a NBER paper.

If $Y_t$ grows at the constant rate $g=r$, then
$$
\triangle G_t+\frac{\triangle G_{t+1}}{1+r}+\frac{\triangle G_{t+2}}{(1+r)^2}+\dots$$
can be rewritten as
$$
Y_t \left(\triangle \frac{G_t}{Y_t}+\triangle \frac{G_{t+1}}{Y_{t+1}}+\triangle \frac{G_{t+2}}{Y_{t+2}}+\dots\right)
$$
I think this calculation is from $Y_{t+1}=Y_t (1+r)$ and $\frac{\triangle G_t}{Y_t}=\triangle \left(\frac{G_t}{Y_t}\right)$.
How $\frac{\triangle G_t}{Y_t}=\triangle \left(\frac{G_t}{Y_t}\right)$ relationship can be established?
Or are there any other missing clues I didn't noticed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How $\frac{\triangle G_t}{Y_t}=\triangle \left(\frac{G_t}{Y_t}\right)$
> relationship can be established?

If $\Delta G_t={G_t-G_{t-1}}$ and $Y_t$ is fixed:

$$
\frac{\Delta G_t}{Y_t}=\frac {G_t-G_{t-1}}{Y_t}=\frac {G_t}{Y_t}-\frac {G_{t-1}}{Y_t}=\Delta \left(\frac{G_t}{Y_t}\right)
$$.

It is just a different way of writing the same thing.